# Migration From Oracle to PostgreSQL Encoding Errors

Tags: oracle, postgresql, csv, encoding, utf-8

I'm working on migrating data from an oracle database to a postgresql database. I running into a problem where I export the data from oracle, using Stored Procedure, and importing it into postgresql. When I try to import the data into postgresql I get this error:

ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xcb 0xcf
CONTEXT:  COPY project, line 810

I found that Oracle Database set by defult will be encoded in ASCII so the CSV file will be normally outputs in ASCII where as in Postgres DB by default encoded in UTF-8 which does not allow to accept ASCII

So Either at the time of exporting the data from Oracle to CSV file i need to encode with UTF-8 with stored procedure i did try with following at oracle it does not worked.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE export_main(dir VARCHAR2, file_name VARCHAR2)
  IS
 select_stmt VARCHAR2(100) := 'SELECT MTYPE || '','' || MNO FROM MAIN';
    cur INTEGER;
    file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    row_value VARCHAR2(4000);
    ret INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    -- Open a cursor for the specified SELECT statement
    cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, select_stmt, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    ret := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);

    -- All columns were concatenated into single value in SELECT
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(cur, 1, row_value, 4000);

    -- Open the file for writing
    --file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(UPPER(dir), file_name, 'w', 32767);
file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR(UPPER(dir), file_name, 'w', 32767);
    -- Export rows one by one
    LOOP
       ret := DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(cur);
       EXIT WHEN ret = 0;

       -- Get the value
       row_value := NULL;
       DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(cur, 1, row_value);

       -- Write the row to the file
      -- UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file, row_value);
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE_NCHAR(file, TO_NCHAR(row_value));
    END LOOP;

     UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(file);
     DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);

    EXCEPTION WHEN NOT_LOGGED_ON THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('A program issues a database call without being connected to Oracle.');
  END;
```

Or else at the time of importing the data from CSV file at the postgres DB i need to encode with UTF-8 with Stored Proc
here is the script at Postgres

```
begin
    set schema 'public';
    raise notice 'CSV PATH: %,TABLE NAME: %',csv_path,target_table;
   execute format('truncate %I ',target_table);
    execute format('copy %I from %L WITH (FORMAT csv)',target_table, csv_path);
    return;
end;
```

Do you want to see the CSV file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SET client_encoding='latin1'` to tell postgres the encoding of the data you are sending. Replace latin1 with the encoding that was used in the oracle database.

A list of character sets supported by postgres can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/multibyte.html). This list also mentions SQL_ASCII but as ASCII is only fully standardized for values 0-127 not values 128-255. So these higher values cannot be converted to UTF8 as it is not defined what they mean.

Comment: I need it done with script.Not by terminal anyhow it does not persist once session or machine is restarted.Its temporary.

Comment: This is not a terminal SET command it is a postgresql SET command.